# Very slooooow simulation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to simulate a small UAV flying over a terrain, with a lidar (ray) sensor and a camera.  I have been successful with a straight flight, but the simulation is very slow.  The sensors have a rate of 10 Hz, but the images and lidar data are generated with several seconds 10-20 between frames.  This is slow, but tolerable.  When I try a banked turn, the simulation slows to a frame every 20-30 minutes.  I am using the .sdf file and plugin below.  The plugin was generated using a Matlab script to create the banked turn.  The heightmap (mtn_height.jpg) is at a resolution of 2049x2049 pixels and the texture (texture_trimmed.png) is of resolution 3993x3992 pixels.

Why is this so slow?  I realize this is a lot of computation, but I am amazed that the banked turn takes so much longer than the straight flight over the same terrain.  Is there some way to speed this up?  Am I using a very inefficient method?

I thought I read that the ray sensor could be sped up using a GPU.  Is this available, and if so, how do I get and use it?

Thanks.

1.0 1.0 1.0 1
      0.5 0.5 0.5 1
      false
    

    
      1000
      0.0005
      0.3

```
<model name="heightmap">
  <static>true</static>
  <link name="height">
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <heightmap>
          <uri>file://media/materials/textures/wasatch_calls_fort_canyon/mtn_height.jpg</uri>
          <size>1000 1000 530</size>
          <pos>0 0 100</pos>
        </heightmap>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual_abcedf">
  <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
      <geometry>
        <heightmap>
          <use_terrain_paging>false</use_terrain_paging>
          <texture>
            <diffuse>file://media/materials/textures/wasatch_calls_fort_canyon/texture_trimmed.png</diffuse>
            <normal>file://media/materials/textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
            <size>1000</size>
          </texture>
          <uri>file://media/materials/textures/wasatch_calls_fort_canyon/mtn_height.jpg</uri>
          <size>1000 1000 530</size>
          <pos>0 0 100</pos>
        </heightmap>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>
```

```
<model name='texelcamera'>
  <link name='link'>
    <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 1.57079 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>1</ixx>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyy>1</iyy>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
        <izz>1</izz>
      </inertia>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
    </inertial> 
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
    <sensor name='camera' type='camera'>
      <pose frame='texsensor'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <camera name='__default__'>
        <horizontal_fov>0.35</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>1024</width>
          <height>350</height>
      <format>BGR_INT8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>2000</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>  <!--For 1.0 m spacing -->
       <visualize>true</visualize>
    </sensor>
    <sensor name='laser' type='ray'>
      <pose frame='texsensor'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>210</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.175</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.175</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>1</samples>
            <min_angle>0</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.08</min>
          <max>2000</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
      </ray>
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate> <!--  For 1.0 m spacing -->
      <visualize>true</visualize>
    </sensor>
    <gravity>false</gravity>
   </link>
  <static>false</static>
  <allow_auto_disable>true</allow_auto_disable>
  <plugin name='push_animate' filename='libanimated_box.so'/>
  <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
</model>
```

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <ignition/math.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace gazebo
{
class AnimatedBox : public ModelPlugin
{
public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)
{
this->model = _parent;
gazebo::common::PoseAnimationPtr anim(
new gazebo::common::PoseAnimation("test", 20.455694, true));

```
    gazebo::common::PoseKeyFrame *key;

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(0.000000);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-188.466132, -229.347724, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001306, 0.000000, 1.636880));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(0.343233);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-188.806868, -224.210510, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001306, 0.000000, 1.636880));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(0.686442);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-189.146074, -219.073566, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001446, 0.000000, 1.636571));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(1.029624);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-189.483589, -213.936920, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001606, 0.000000, 1.636229));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(1.372775);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-189.819226, -208.800605, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001790, 0.000000, 1.635849));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(1.715893);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-190.152768, -203.664659, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.002003, 0.000000, 1.635423));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(2.058973);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-190.483968, -198.529127, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.002251, 0.000000, 1.634947));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(2.402011);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-190.812536, -193.394058, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.002541, 0.000000, 1.634410));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(2.745001);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-191.138135, -188.259513, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.002883, 0.000000, 1.633802));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(3.087938);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-191.460367, -183.125562, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.003287, 0.000000, 1.633111));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(3.430814);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-191.778762, -177.992287, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.003768, 0.000000, 1.632321));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(3.773621);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-192.092761, -172.859788, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.004346, 0.000000, 1.631412));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(4.116347);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-192.401692, -167.728182, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.005046, 0.000000, 1.630361));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(4.458981);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-192.704743, -162.597613, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.005900, 0.000000, 1.629135));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(4.801508);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-193.000927, -157.468254, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.006951, 0.000000, 1.627698));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(5.143909);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-193.289027, -152.340322, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.008259, 0.000000, 1.625996));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(5.486163);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-193.567534, -147.214080, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.009901, 0.000000, 1.623966));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(5.828241);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-193.834557, -142.089864, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.011985, 0.000000, 1.621521));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(6.170109);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.087702, -136.968094, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.014663, 0.000000, 1.618545));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(6.511724);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.323901, -131.849313, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.018143, 0.000000, 1.614884));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(6.853032);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.539184, -126.734220, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.022717, 0.000000, 1.610329));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(7.193965);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.728355, -121.623731, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.028796, 0.000000, 1.604592));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(7.534435);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.884545, -116.519057, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.036949, 0.000000, 1.597280));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(7.874337);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.998599, -111.421813, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.047935, 0.000000, 1.587853));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(8.213537);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-195.058279, -106.334157, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.062701, 0.000000, 1.575587));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(8.551884);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-195.047285, -101.258963, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.082234, 0.000000, 1.559548));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(8.889219);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.944278, -96.199992, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.107082, 0.000000, 1.538632));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(9.225412);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.722415, -91.161980, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.136337, 0.000000, 1.511772));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(9.560434);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-194.350424, -86.150439, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.166226, 0.000000, 1.478398));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(9.894446);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-193.796629, -81.170955, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.189626, 0.000000, 1.439130));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(10.227859);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-193.036358, -76.227878, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.198621, 0.000000, 1.396263));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(10.561273);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-192.060147, -71.322877, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.189626, 0.000000, 1.353396));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(10.895285);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-190.877460, -66.454284, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.166226, 0.000000, 1.314128));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(11.230307);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-189.512969, -61.617747, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.136337, 0.000000, 1.280754));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(11.566500);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-187.998351, -56.807682, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.107082, 0.000000, 1.253894));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(11.903835);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-186.364876, -52.018575, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.082234, 0.000000, 1.232979));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(12.242182);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-184.639389, -47.245692, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.062701, 0.000000, 1.216940));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(12.581382);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-182.843227, -42.485271, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.047935, 0.000000, 1.204674));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(12.921284);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-180.992690, -37.734437, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.036949, 0.000000, 1.195247));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(13.261754);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-179.100019, -32.991033, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.028796, 0.000000, 1.187935));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(13.602687);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-177.174367, -28.253444, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.022717, 0.000000, 1.182198));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(13.943995);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-175.222601, -23.520460, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.018143, 0.000000, 1.177643));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(14.285610);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-173.249920, -18.791164, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.014663, 0.000000, 1.173982));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(14.627478);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-171.260294, -14.064856, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.011985, 0.000000, 1.171006));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(14.969556);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-169.256789, -9.340995, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.009901, 0.000000, 1.168561));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(15.311810);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-167.241800, -4.619159, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.008259, 0.000000, 1.166530));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(15.654211);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-165.217219, 0.100986, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.006951, 0.000000, 1.164829));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(15.996738);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-163.184553, 4.819705, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.005900, 0.000000, 1.163391));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(16.339372);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-161.145020, 9.537214, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.005046, 0.000000, 1.162166));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(16.682098);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-159.099607, 14.253685, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.004346, 0.000000, 1.161115));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(17.024905);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-157.049126, 18.969263, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.003768, 0.000000, 1.160206));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(17.367781);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-154.994249, 23.684066, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.003287, 0.000000, 1.159416));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(17.710718);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-152.935536, 28.398192, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.002883, 0.000000, 1.158725));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(18.053708);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-150.873455, 33.111725, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.002541, 0.000000, 1.158117));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(18.396746);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-148.808405, 37.824734, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.002251, 0.000000, 1.157580));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(18.739826);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-146.740724, 42.537279, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.002003, 0.000000, 1.157103));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(19.082944);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-144.670699, 47.249411, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001790, 0.000000, 1.156678));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(19.426095);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-142.598581, 51.961174, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001606, 0.000000, 1.156298));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(19.769277);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-140.524585, 56.672605, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001446, 0.000000, 1.155955));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(20.112485);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-138.448896, 61.383738, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001306, 0.000000, 1.155647));

    key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(20.455694);
    key->Translation(ignition::math::Vector3d(-136.371679, 66.094602, 1250.000000));
    key->Rotation(ignition::math::Quaterniond(0.001306, 0.000000, 1.155647));

    _parent->SetAnimation(anim);
}
private: physics::ModelPtr model;
private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;
```

};
GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(AnimatedBox)
}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15525/very-slooooow-simulation/) by [sebudge](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2840/sebudge/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2017-03-03**:
is it slow because of a low real time factor or low FPS?

Real time factor:

1. increase max_step_size
2. Reduce ode  from default 50 to something lower (sacrifices accuracy)

FPS:

1. turn off camera visualization by setting  to false.
2. reduce heightmap resolution
3. reduce texture resolution

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2017-03-03**:
is it slow because of a low real time factor or low FPS?

Real time factor:

1. increase max_step_size,
2. Reduce ode  from default 50 to something lower (sacrifices accuracy).

FPS:

1. turn off camera visualization by setting  to false,
2. reduce heightmap resolution,
3. reduce texture resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As usual, the answer for my immediate problem was simple.

I changed the sensor type to "gpu_ray" and the physics tags to the following.

0.05
      0.2
      1
      
        
          quick
          2
          1.4
        
        
          0
          1
          0
          0

With the changes, everything worked fine, and the entire simulation executed in about 5 minutes (as opposed to better than one day before it crashed).

---

Originally posted by [sebudge](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2840/sebudge/) with karma: 36 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1